# C# XmlDocument.LoadXml(string) failure (NotSupportedException)

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to load a string value into a XML document in C#.  This code has been working fine up until recently.  I cannot figure out why it is now failing...

```
strJournalReturn = ServiceConnect.PostInventoryJournal(userName, password, 
type, effectiveDate, fromWarehouse, toWarehouse, department, project, asset, 
workOrder, jobNumber, reason, lTransactions);

    if (!strJournalReturn.Contains("INTERNALERROR"))
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.LoadXml(strJournalReturn);
        }
```

the strJournalReturn value is...

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<JOURNAL-
SERVICE>\n<ERROR>1</ERROR>\n<ERRORMESSAGES>\n<ERRORMESSAGE>DEPARTMENT is 
required for direct issues & reserves with 
backorders</ERRORMESSAGE>\n</ERRORMESSAGES>\n</JOURNAL-SERVICE>"
```

This is throwing an exception "NotSupportedException".  Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated.

I apologize in advance if the detail on this post is not enough as this is my first time posting here.

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't think this is about the error in the xml, but an error attempting to load the xml into a `XmlDocument`.

Comment: That is the error I am expecting to get back in this scenario.  However, when trying to load that XML string into the XmlDocument, it blows up with "NotSupportedException".  I assume the XML is not formatted correctly but I am not seeing any problems.

Comment: The string content isn't xml encoded correctly. Eg &amp;

Comment: You might want to consider switching to the Linq-to-Xml DOM instead.

Comment: It's the ampersand, yes. Make sure whatever produces this does its xml encoding correctly.

Comment: Yes it was indeed the ampersand.  I was focused on the tags themselves and never thought to even look at the message coming back.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Having a method with so many parameters is considered an anti-pattern.  *Code Complete, 2nd edition (McConnell)*, page 178: "Limit the number of a routine's parameters to about seven.  Seven is the magic number for people's comprehension.  Research has found that people generally cannot keep track of more than seven chunks of information at a time... If you find yourself consistently passing more than a few arguments, the coupling between your routines is too tight.  Design the routine or group of routines to reduce coupling."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string which you want to parse has invalid character like ampersand.(`&`)

```
DEPARTMENT is required for direct issues & reserves with backorders
```

Normally, the xml should be encoded properly. Using `Replace` would be an option before trying to parse it.

```
var str = "<JOURNAL-SERVICE><ERROR>1</ERROR><ERRORMESSAGES>" +
            "<ERRORMESSAGE>DEPARTMENT is required for direct issues & reserves with backorders</ERRORMESSAGE>" +
            "</ERRORMESSAGES></JOURNAL-SERVICE>";
str = str.Replace("&", "&amp;");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
```

But, be sure about that the another non-encoded characters might be contained in the xml.